# Way to store images/content in an app

Tags: objective-c

Need guidance for an app for iOS. I am designing a Facebook kind of app for displaying newsfeed. I want to store a limited number of newsfeed items and images instead of downloading them every time. Since it is limited data how to store them? Core data? Or a file? 
If core data since data changes every time how to manage deletion and insertion optimally? Should query and check for existing data and delete or insert or delete all content and reinsert data?

What is the best method of displaying images to store in arrays or to read every time when loading the newsfeed which should be optimal in performance and memory?

Right now I am storing all the images in an nsmutablearray. And I can see that the animation is not smooth sometimes in a iCarousel.

Comment: Look out for correct grammar and punctuation.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend writing the images to a file, in your app's Documents directory or Cache directory (probably cache, this is what it is for, but see Apple's guidelines and policy on allowable use of storage areas). There are many convenience methods for taking image files and displaying them that make it simple to keep images as files.
For the newsfeed stuff, it depends a bit if it's HTML or text, if you need to search/filter/index it, etc. You could just write .html files same as you do the images if the number is small and the needs are simple.

Comment: thank you for the solution. I am not using html but using imageviews and labels. So, I am thinking of downloading the images and saving the image location to core data.

Comment: Not a bad plan to use CoreData to keep a table of all the images you've cached and the labels that go with each. I do recommend keeping the images in the filesystem rather than as blobs in CoreData though, it's less code and simpler to debug and manage.